# Can I qualify the type of a parameter in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, generics

This is kind of two questions (one more specific than the other).

If I have a method like this:

```
Public Function Blah(String Foo)
End Function
```

Can I qualify Foo against another type (for instance can I require that Foo be a String that also implements IInterface?).

I'm imagining something vaguely similar to this:

```
Public Function Blah(RandomObject Foo Where RandomObject Is IInterface)
End Function
```

Additionally, is there any way to qualify the Type parameter?

For instance, can I require that the Type I take as a parameter is of a particular class tree?

```
Public Function Blah(Type t Where Type Of String)
End Function
```

I should mention that I am using this in the context of a property of an attribute so the class declaration itself cannot be generic (this is purely focused on qualifying a method parameter rather than typing a class and its methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a case for generics to me. Your method signature would be something like this in VB.NET:

```
Public Function Blah(Of T As {IImplementedByT})(Foo As T)
```

This specifies that Foo can be of any type T as long as T implements IImplementedByT. Note that this method can be generic without the containing class needing to be generic. If you want T to be a class derived from RandomClass that also implements this interface, you can specify both constraints:

```
Public Function Blah(Of T As {RandomClass, IImplementedByT})(Foo As T)
```

Comment: Thanks - this was interesting and useful but I found out what I wanted to do was something else. I was trying to apply this to properties but you can't have type parameters on a set clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the first for a *generic* type, but not for a nongeneric type. Basically a variable (including a parameter) can only have one compile-time type, so you can't say "it has to be a `Foo` and an `IBar` - you have to pick one or the other. Generics let you say "it has to be some type `T` where `T` derives from `Foo` and implements `IBar`" though.

Generics is a huge topic - too big to cover in a Stack Overflow answer - but Microsoft has a [good introductory article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379608.aspx).

As for your second question - no, you can't do that. The `Type` value will only be known at execution time, so it has to be an execution time check. You can write that check fairly easily though, with [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx).

Comment: Thanks - I thought I understood generics well enough but I couldn't seem to get the VB.NET syntax right for qualifying a method unless I qualified the class too.  As for the Type check, I guess this is one  thing compilers could work on but you're right I didn't consider dynamic typing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "Foo be a String that also implements IInterface".

string class is sealed, so you can't inherit from it & hence you cant implement an interface on top of it.

I hope I am on the right page.

Comment: Okay String was a bad example, assume a non-sealed class then.